# Bathymetry from Satellite Imagery Using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, bathymetry

I have developed a GEE script that processes Sentinel2 imagery to derive water depths by training against an input of real measurements. The results show a broad scattering of random pixel 'depths' rather than a smoother transition to a changing seafloor elevation. Is there anyway I can improve the script to overcome this?

```
  [174.7500, -36.5700],
  [174.8500, -36.5700],
  [174.8500, -36.6500],
  [174.7500, -36.6500]
]);

var lineEntries = [
  [11.4, 174.7591663, -36.60190802],
  [12, 174.7734624, -36.59918441],
  [8.4, 174.7684059, -36.60476955],
  [3, 174.7806565, -36.59998885],
  [12.6, 174.7823113, -36.59592066],
  [2, 174.7778524, -36.60559697],
  [2, 174.7673716, -36.60821716],
  [13, 174.7648204, -36.59621946],
  [14.4, 174.7742669, -36.59265692],
  [3, 174.7652341, -36.61288294],
  [9.1, 174.7616256, -36.60780345],
  [1.2, 174.7690035, -36.61720395],
  [3.4, 174.7646365, -36.61773259],

];

var measurements = ee.FeatureCollection(
  lineEntries.map(function(entry) {
    var depth = entry[0];
    var xcoord = entry[1];
    var ycoord = entry[2];
    var point = ee.Geometry.Point([xcoord, ycoord]);
    return ee.Feature(point, { Depth: depth, xcoord: xcoord, ycoord: ycoord });
  })
);

var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-05-01')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
  .filterMetadata('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE', 'greater_than', 20);

var medianImage = sentinel2.median().clip(geometry);

var ratioB2B3 = medianImage.select('B2').divide(medianImage.select('B3')).rename('ratioB2B3');

var processedMeasurements = measurements.map(function(feature) {
  var depth = feature.getNumber('Depth').toInt();
  var xcoord = feature.getNumber('xcoord');
  var ycoord = feature.getNumber('ycoord');
  var testPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([xcoord, ycoord]);
  var sampledB2B3 = ratioB2B3.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), testPoint, 10);
  var ratioB2B3Value = ee.Number(sampledB2B3.get('ratioB2B3'));

  if (ratioB2B3Value) {
    return feature.set('ratioB2B3', ratioB2B3Value).set('Depth', depth);
  } else {
    return feature.set('ratioB2B3', ratioB2B3Value || 0).set('Depth', depth || 0);
  }
}).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['Depth', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'ratioB2B3']));

var classifierOptions = {
  numberOfTrees: 100,
};

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(classifierOptions).train({
  features: processedMeasurements,
  classProperty: 'Depth',
  inputProperties: ['ratioB2B3'],
});

var classifiedImage = ratioB2B3.classify(classifier);

// Create water mask using NDWI
var ndwi = medianImage.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
var waterMask = ndwi.gt(0);

// Apply water mask to the classified image
var classifiedWaterImage = classifiedImage.updateMask(waterMask);

// Set visualization parameters
var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 15,
  palette: ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

// Display the classified water image with the visualization parameters
Map.addLayer(classifiedWaterImage, visParams, 'Predicted Bathymetry');

// Export the classified water image as a GeoTIFF
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classifiedWaterImage,
  description: 'Predicted_Bathymetry',
  scale: 20,
  region: geometry
[![Bathymetry][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFLCx.jpg
```